# django-pyodbc queries returning fields with ANSI Padding Status ON, how to strip out whitespace?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

So I am querying an SQL Server DB which has many CHAR fields with ANSI Padding Status ON. This means that for a CHAR(10) field, the value may be "123" but I'm instead receiving "123......." (whitespace) in the result.

Is there a best practice method to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [python's strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) before you save it.

Or add a method to the model which strips whitespace from the property when called.  You could even override the default getter method.

```
@property
def stripped_foo(self):
    return self.foo.strip()
```

Comment: This is not for saving to the DB, this is for pulling data from the DB. It outputs with the extra whitespace. I'm aware I could just use strip everywhere I make queries with this model, but that seems redundant. There should be a single place I can define the value of this field post-query.